# Validating argv[] input in class constructor

Tags: c++

I am working on a class assignment, where I need to create a stack of structs. I am supposed to dynamically create an array of pointers, size based on a single command line input. The value passed to constructor should be greater than 2, if not, set it to 10.  Whenever I pass arrSize = stoi(argv[1]) to Class(int) it returns whatever I put without changing it.

Even if I make int arrSize = 1 manually, it still does not properly filter the values. I believe if-else statements in a constructor are okay, as I am not aware of another way to test and change the passed arg; I also can only have a single constructor in the class, that takes the argv value as an argument.

I feel like I am making some sort of pathetically simple mistake, but I have been trying to figure this out since Thursday. I have finished the rest of the program, this is the last thing I need to fix.

I cannot figure out if the variable is being passed as a const in some arcane way, or if the constructor isn't being validly called, or if its something else entirely. Any help greatly appreciated.

Class constructor:

```
Stack::Stack(int arrSize){
    this->top = -1;
    if (arrSize < 2){
                this->size = 10;
        stack = new Data*[size];
    }
    else{
                this->size = arrSize;
        stack = new Data*[size];
    }
}
```

Class attributes:

```
private:
    int top;
    int size;
    Data **stack; //Data is a struct with int "id" and string "information"
```

Driver code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    try{
    if (argc > 2){
    std::cout << "Please enter only a single parameter in the command line" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
    std::string strtemp;
    Data myStruct;    //initializing empty struct for pop()
    int arraySize = std::stoi(argv[1]);   //converting argv[1] to int, store in arraySize
    Stack stack(arraySize);     //create Stack object, passing arraySize as arg
        ...truncated...}
```

Comment: Formatting got all jacked up, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Why the duplicated code in your initializer? Just figure out `arrSize` and go for it down the same path. Also consider [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) as a way of better organizing your code, and **do not forget** the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Consider using std::vector<Data> (instead of manually allocating memory using new, your current code is likely to have memory leaks at some point), and use `std::size_t` instead of `int` for data structure sizes. If you can't use std::vector then your teacher isn't teaching you C++ as it should be used.

Comment: Perhaps you want `arrSize < 3` (not 2) to conform the "greater than 2" clause

Comment: @tadman I duplicated because I thought there was a scope issue. Thank you for the links, I was not aware of the rule of three!

PepijnKramer This is a data structures class, the main point is to recreate stacks, linked lists, and the like. I don't think we're prevented from using vectors, its just not the point of the assignment.
I think the teacher's purpose is to teach us the low level stuff as building blocks for the industry standards. He was a production manager in industry, so I am assuming he is doing this on purpose.
Ripi2 Thanks, but just a typo; should be arrSize > 1

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `this->` syntax if you use different names between parameters and members.  One method to do this is to prefix all your data members with `m_`.  Another method is to append all members with "_".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for the tip, I was just at a loss for why it wouldn't take.

Comment: ". I think the teacher's purpose is to teach us the low level stuff as building blocks for the industry standards." Depends on what "industry" and what "standards". Modern, *effective* C++ stays away from pointers and direct allocations when possible, instead using containers and structures designed to be cheap to copy and move. This is a fancy way of saying "it involves an obscene amount of `std::vector`" as that tool is extremely versatile and performs very well.

Comment: While it's a good thing to know the low-level fundamentals, and learning that should absolutely be encouraged, it's a really rough way to start learning C++. Remember, all programming is just a spot on the abstraction continuum from the atoms that make up the physical transistors to the business objective you're trying to achieve. You need to pick a spot along that space to start learning and the space that allows you to *solve problems* usually works the best for learning. You can then work your way both up and down the continuum from there.

Comment: You are learning fundamentals of data structures.  In the industry, we would use library functions and refrain from writing our own code.  Using libraries means that most of the library code has already been debugged (test), reducing the development time.  All we have to do is to prove that the library meets our requirements. :-)

Comment: So it should be "Hey, this `std::unordered_set` is really neat, I wonder how it works and how I could implement my own that's a bit better for my particular use case" instead of "What is a hash? What is a set? What am I even doing?" It's har to build things from scratch when you've never seen or used that thing ever before. It's like learning to drive by first manufacturing a car from scrap steel.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the insight, I came across the suggestions to use smart pointers and vectors over and over while researching my problem. I will definitely learn to use them for my actual programming in the future.

Comment: You should study the reverse.  Given the needs to process data First In, Last Out, you should come up with a Stack structure, then use `std::stack`.

Comment: @Kom *I was not aware of the rule of three!* -- *I think the teacher's purpose is to teach us the low level stuff* -- The teacher was supposed to give you fair warning or have taught this to you (the rule of 3) **before** having you embark on this endeavor.  It makes no sense to send a student into this without letting them know what the basics are of building a class and have that class have correct copy-semantics.

Answer (score 1):

There was actually nothing wrong with the code I posted, I was not using the size attribute properly, and it was causing an error with the initialization.

I appreciate all the suggestions for better style, I will take them into account. As to the question of using vectors, this is a data structures class, so I think the main point is to learn to reconstruct stacks, linked lists, hash tables from a computer science standpoint; rather than programming standpoint.

Thank you all!

Comment: *I think the main point is to learn to reconstruct stacks, linked lists, hash tables from a computer science standpoint; rather than programming standpoint.* -- That may work with other computer languages, but using C++ to learn data structures requires you to know C++ to the extent of knowing how to build a class properly.  You cannot take what you have in a data structures book and attempt to code it in C++ with none to very little C++ skills, since all that will happen will be problems not actually related to the data structure itself, but instead of C++.

Comment: In the book "[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://web.mit.edu/6.001/6.037/sicp.pdf)", the language that was chosen Lisp (Scheme) was chosen specifically because it was so simple to learn that the class could focus on the material rather than be distracted by a complex programming language.  I daresay that C++ is one of the more complicated programming languages available.